# html video tag fullscreen control does not work properly with Chrome

Tags: html

I do not speak English well..

jsp sources :

```html
<video controls controlsList="nodownload" name="media" width="100%" id="vodArea">         
  <source src="~~~" type="video/mp4" id="vodAreaSrc">
</video>
```

[image: play]

There is no problem here.

When the full screen button in a video is clicked, Full screen is not maintained in chrome. (Firefox is no problem)

It returns to the original screen after it becomes full screen.

example url

> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

- chrome version : 73.0.3683.75 (64bit)
- os : window10 64bit

Why is there a problem with my Chrome?

Comment: Full screen works on my Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121. What version do you have? Perhaps you have a Chrome Extension that's affecting video playback. What happens if you try in an Incognito Window where, on my machine, there are no Extensions loaded?

Comment: Chrome version 73.0.3683.75. The same thing happens in the incognito window. And Thank you for modifying the post!!!! : )

Answer (score 0):

[Instructions here](https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Google-Chrome-YouTube-Fullscreen-Glitch) are for youtube but these may still apply.

1. uninstall themes
2. disable extensions
   launch chrome with switches: "chrome.exe --disable-extensions"
3. turn off hardware acceleration
4. Reset Chrome to default settings. Removing default settings may fix the full-screen problem, though keep in mind it will also remove your current settings:

   - Click ⋮ in the top-right corner.
   - Click Settings.
   - Scroll down and click Advanced.
   - Scroll down and click Restore settings to their original defaults.
   - Click Reset settings when prompted.
5. reinstall chrome

I'd try 1-3 first, then 4, then if all else fails, 5.

Comment: I tried until the end but failed. If I can not do it in a variety of ways, I will use PIP mode.......

Thank you for your comment. : )